# Write apache spark rdd to multilple s3 folders

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, java-8, partition

There is an JavaRDD of Foo objects. And, Foo has a date column.

```
class Foo {
 String id;
 String date;
}
```

And here is a list of Foo objects,

```
1, 2019-08-01
2, 2019-08-01
3, 2019-08-02
4, 2019-08-02
5, 2019-08-02
```

I want to save serialized Foo objects in s3 this way i.e they are partitioned by date column in s3,

```
s3://foo/2019-08-01/  ==> contains files with Foo objects with ids 1,2
s3://foo/2019-08-02/  ==> contains files with Foo objects with 3,4,5
```

How do I do this? Because, the saveAsText takes a single output path. Ideally, we need to partition the RDD first based on date and then write each partition to a specific output path.

```
JavaRDD<Foo> fooRDD = sc.textFile(...)
fooRDD.saveAsText(outputPath);
```

I tried partitioning the RDD first based on date column. Now, I am not sure how to write this pair RDD to s3.

```
//create a <date, list of Foo objects>. 
JavaPairRDD<String,LinkedList<Foo>> partiontinedRDD
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `partiontinedRDD.partitionBy` to partition RDD and then call `saveAsTextFile`. It will create a separate file for each key:

`count.partitionBy(new HashPartitioner((int) count.keys().count())).saveAsTextFile("/tmp/files");`